# Getting Jquery to work with a include file that is using jquery as well

Tags: jquery, html, header, include

I am new to Jquery - I have an include file in my HTML below the header (for the nav) and the nav uses Jquery for the drop down. I am sure its an easy solution.

But when I add another jquery code to my html in the header it either does work - or breaks the header code.

How can I get both to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code here or create a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ if you want someone to  be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I ran into a similar issue before, one option is to remove the 'included' jQuery using something like:

```
$('script[src*=jquery\\.min\\.js]').remove().
```

Of course you'll want to narrow your selector as much as possible to only remove the one javascript include.